# app crashes when loading in android

Tags: android, crash, view, loading

unfortunately my app crashes when this activity is being loaded:

```
public class ManagerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


private TabHost th;

private EditText addpray1;
private EditText addplace1;
private EditText addtime1;
private Button addpray1Button;

private EditText removepray1;
private EditText removeplace1;
private EditText removetime1;
private Button removepray1Button;

private EditText addpray2;
private EditText addplace2;
private EditText addtime2;
private Button addpray2Button;

private EditText removepray2;
private EditText removeplace2;
private EditText removetime2;
private Button removepray2Button;

private EditText addtitlemessage;
private EditText addinfomessage;
private Button addmessagebutton;

private EditText removetitlemessage;
private Button removemessagebutton;

private EditText addtitleevent;
private EditText addinfoevent;
private Button addeventbutton;

private EditText removetitleevent;
private Button removeeventbutton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.manager);


    th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);


    InitTabs(th);
    InitFields();

    addpray1Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    removepray1Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    addpray2Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    removepray2Button.setOnClickListener(this);
    addeventbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    removeeventbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    addmessagebutton.setOnClickListener(this);
    removeeventbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void InitTabs(TabHost th){
    th.setup();

    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator("עדכון הודעות");
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    specs.setIndicator("עדכון אירועים");
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    specs.setIndicator("עדכון זמני השבת");
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab4);
    specs.setIndicator("עדכון זמני יום חול");
    th.addTab(specs);



}

private void InitFields() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    addpray1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addPray1);
    addplace1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.place1);
    addtime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time1);
    addpray1Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPrayButton1);

    removepray1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.removePray1);
    removeplace1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_remove1);
    removetime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.place_remove1);
    removepray1Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removePrayButton1);

    addpray2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pray2);
    addplace2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.place2);
    addtime2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time2);
    addpray2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPrayButton2);

    removepray2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.removePray2);
    removeplace2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.place_remove2);
    removetime2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_remove2);
    removepray2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removePrayButton2);

    addtitlemessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleMessage);
    addinfomessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageInfo);
    addmessagebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addMessageButton);

    removetitlemessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.removeMessage);
    removemessagebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeMessageButton);

    addtitleevent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addEvent);
    addinfoevent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eventInfo);
    addeventbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addEventButton);

    removetitleevent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.removeEvent);
    removeeventbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removeEventButton);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

and the xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/addMessage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="הוספת הודעה"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/titleMessage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/addMessage"
                        android:hint="כותרת"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/messageInfo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/titleMessage"
                        android:hint="מידע"
                        android:lines="4"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/addMessageButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/messageInfo"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="הוסף" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/removeMessage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="הסרת הודעה"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/titleMessage_remove"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/removeMessage"
                        android:hint="כותרת"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/removeMessageButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/titleMessage_remove"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="הסר" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/addEvent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="הוספת אירוע"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/titleEvent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/addEvent"
                        android:hint="כותרת"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/eventInfo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/titleEvent"
                        android:hint="מידע"
                        android:lines="4"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/addEventButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/eventInfo"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="הוסף" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/removeEvent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="הסרת אירוע"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/titleEvent_remove"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/removeEvent"
                        android:hint="כותרת"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/removeEventButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/titleEvent_remove"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="הסר" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/addPray1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="הוספת תפילה"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/pray1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/addPray1"
                        android:hint="תפילה" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/place1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/pray1"
                        android:hint="מקום" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/time1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/place1"
                        android:hint="שעה" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/addPrayButton1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/time1"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="הוסף" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/removePray1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="הסרת תפילה"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/pray_remove1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/removePray1"
                        android:hint="תפילה" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/place_remove1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/pray_remove1"
                        android:hint="מקום" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/time_remove1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/place_remove1"
                        android:hint="שעה" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/removePrayButton1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/time_remove1"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="הסר" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/addPray2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="הוספת תפילה"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/pray2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/addPray2"
                        android:hint="תפילה" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/place2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/pray2"
                        android:hint="מקום" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/time2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/place2"
                        android:hint="שעה" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/addPrayButton2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/time2"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="הוסף" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/removePray2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="הסרת תפילה"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/pray_remove2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/removePray2"
                        android:hint="תפילה" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/place_remove2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/pray_remove2"
                        android:hint="מקום" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/time_remove2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/place_remove2"
                        android:hint="שעה" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/removePrayButton2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/time_remove2"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="הסר" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

   </LinearLayout>
```

i guess it's because i'm loading a lot of views...

I'm also wanna to add a progress bar that works while the layout is loading until its done.

how can i fix that?

thanks :)

Comment: post your log-cat error..

Comment: Don't try to guess why the app is crashing, have a look at the LogCat and share it with us ;)

Comment: Just saying, you probably got the declaration switched. `removeplace1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_remove1); removetime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.place_remove1);`

Comment: I think `TabHost` requires a ID that is defined in `android` namespace. i.e. instead of `android:id="@+id/tabhost"`, OP should refer to the `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"`...

Comment: but when i use the ID that they defined it gives me an error on that line th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);